# In VBA/Access get value from current record when changing records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database. I have a map control embedded in a form (using MapInfo, but that's not important). When a user goes from one record to another I would like the map to re-centre on the appropriate coordinates. To do this I need to get the coordinates which are stored in the current row of the table which is the data source for the form. My question is how I access this value. This is pretty simple, right?

I have worked out that the "On Current" event is triggered when the record is changed but I can't seem to refer to the xcoord and ycoord fields in the current row.

[This page](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/modules/recordset.php) seems to suggest that I need to create a module to do this. Surely there's a simpler way?

Thanks in advance!

Update: If I put a pair of textbox controls in the form that display the x and y coordinates then I can access them by doing Me.x_coord. Is this *the* answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Access VBA you can reference the fields of a bound form's recordsource with the syntax:

```
Forms!your_form_name!your_field_name
```

In your case, you can grab the current `x_coord` with `Me!x_coord`.  No need to bind it to a control to get the data.